# Eventbrite Event Lists widget not working

Tags: events, widget, eventbrite

I have played with the other widgets on the Eventbrite's API page and got each of them to work. The only one that I'm having difficulty with is the [Event List widget](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/widgets/#list).

I've hunted around online for a tutorial with more information or anything to see what I might be doing wrong, but have not been successful.

When I copy and paste the text, nothing shows up. So I tried changing the API Key and ID to mine and nothing shows up. Does anyone know if it no longer works or if there's something more that I have to add to the code that isn't too clear in the description for the Event List widget?

Answer (score 0):

What languuage are you working in?

Eventbrite's open source example code section should provide some additional examples:
http://eventbrite.github.com/#examples

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and I noticed the first script tag in the example from EventBrite is missing "http:" in the src attribute. Once I added this, it worked.

`<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

should instead be...

`<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`